# Second View Not Appearing When App is Run

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been working on this weird bug for about a day now and it has completely baffled me. I added a ImageButton to a frame layout, and when I look at the layout preview the buttons there, but when I run the app on my phone it isn't there; however when I turn my phone sideways then the button appears with non of it's properties set. I posted the layout xml file as well as some accompanying photos of the layout and some of the directory. Any help would be appreciated, Thank You.

P.S. For some reason stack overflow is acting real weird with the images so I am trying to copy the links in a comment or something

Snippet Not Working:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLastUpdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Update: HH:MM DD/MM/YYYY"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonRefresh"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_reload"
            android:tint="#2196F3"
            android:layout_marginStart="340dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            tools:ignore="UseAppTint" />
    </FrameLayout>

Entire Code:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/black">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewLastUpdate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Last Update: HH:MM DD/MM/YYYY"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonRefresh"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_reload"
                        android:tint="#2196F3"
                        android:layout_marginStart="340dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        tools:ignore="UseAppTint" />
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewUPS"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="UPS: XXX"
                        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewMains"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mains: XXX"
                        android:layout_marginStart="210dp"/>
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewUPSTemp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="UPS Temp: XXX"
                        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewSOP"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Power Source: XXX"
                        android:layout_marginStart="210dp"/>
                </FrameLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewAdvancedInfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="More Info . . ."
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#2196F3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
[Image of drawable folders][1]
[Expected layout][2]
[Resulting Layout][3]
[Resulting Layout Side View With Image Artifact][4]
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz5nF.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuO4Z.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVwTy.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZKVq.png

Comment: you're using massive margins here `android:layout_marginStart="340dp"`, chances are you need to do some basics on layouts, just because it looks fine on your emulator doesn't mean it'll work for all device sizes

Comment: @a_local_nobody I had the same idea a few iterations back and removed the textView it shares a FrameLayout with and placed it in the center of the card. The same issue occurred it didn't appear and the artifact was there when I turned my phone sideways.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the directories I found an alternative layout file in layout-v23. The layout didn't match the layout from my main layout folder, but did match what was appearing on my phone. I copied the code from my main layout to the v23 alternative layout, fixing the bug.